# Error Building New Jekyll Site

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I've tried making a blog with Jekyll a few times and have always run into this issue across multiple versions of OSX, Ruby etc. After I run:

```
jekyll new myblog
```

I get this error:

```
/Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2054: warning: else without rescue is useless
/Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2060: warning: else without rescue is useless
/Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2099: warning: else without rescue is useless
/Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2050: syntax error, unexpected modifier_if (SyntaxError)
          if separator.value == 'auto'
            ^
/Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2054: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
/Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2060: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
/Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2095: syntax error, unexpected modifier_if
          if separator.value == 'auto'
            ^
/Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2099: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
/Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2885: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script.rb:34:in `<module:Script>'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script.rb:8:in `<module:Sass>'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/engine.rb:47:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass.rb:99:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.0/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.0/lib/jekyll-sass-converter.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.3/lib/jekyll.rb:200:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.3/exe/jekyll:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I'm running High Sierra v 10.13.3 and have tried all the troubleshooting suggestions I could find. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I actually already had the latest version of Ruby installed but reinstalled just to be sure. I now get this error when I try to make a new jekyll site:

```
/Users/NuriAmari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/jekyll: No such file or directory
```

Any other tips?

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade the ruby version I check its working for 2.3.4
when I tried to use it for `2.1.3` I got the error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ruby_dep requires Ruby version >= 2.2.5, ~> 2.2.
```

Comment: I have updated to the latest version and now get a different error. It seems that jekyll is looking for Ruby in the wrong place. Can I point it to the correct location? I updated my post with the error.

Comment: it seems it still take `ruby 2.1.3`, do you have rvm?
wt was the output of `ruby --version` cmd.

Comment: `ruby --version`  produces `ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]`

Comment: strange in your error it shows `2.1.3`. I suggest you to use `rvm` to manage ruby versions